# Linear Probing in Python

Tags: python, circular-list

About to get back into coding, so I implemented linear probing in Python. How did I do? Anything unnecessary? Am I using "global" right? I originally wanted to use an array with a fixed length, but couldn't get it to work.

```
list = ["x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x"]
state = 0

def main():
#tests
    linearProbing(1)
    linearProbing(1)
    linearProbing(1)
    print(list)

def linearProbing(x):
    global state
    global list
    c = x % len(list)
    while state != 1:
        if list[c] == "x":
            list[c] = x
            state = 1
        elif c == 0:
            c = len(list) - 1
        else:
            c -= 1
    state = 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I using "global" right?

It would be better to not use `global` at all,
by wrapping this in a class,
with `state` and `list` as attributes,
so an instance could reference them with `self.state`, for example.

> How did I do?

`state` is used as a boolean.
So it should be a boolean value,
set to `False` instead of 0 and `True` instead of 1 values.

`list` is not a good name for a variable,
as it shadows a built-in with the same name.

A quick tip: you can write `["x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x"]` simpler as `["x"] * 7`.
In any case, duplicating `"x"` in multiple places (first when you initialize `list`, and then later in `linearProbing`), is not great.
It would be better to put the value `"x"` in a variable, say `FREESPOT = "x"`,
and reuse that everywhere.

Comment: That's the kind of answer I was looking for, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

### Global variables

`list` should not be global, because it limits your function to ever working on one global list, hindering code reuse.  Instead, it should be passed as a parameter.  Since `list` is the name of a built-in type in Python, you should probably avoid using it as the name of a variable — that would break code like `list(range(7))`.

`state` should *absolutely not* be global.  It's just a flag that is used locally within the `linearProbing()` function, and it's always 0 whenever `linearProbing()` is not executing.  Better yet, just don't use flag variables for controlling program flow (see solution below).

Especially if you are a beginner, you should just consider `global` to be taboo, and avoid using it altogether.  There is *always* a better way.

### Other issues

- There is no way to tell when the list is full (at which point the insertion silently fails, leading to probable data loss).
- Using `"x"` as a special value to indicate an available slot is weird.  Typically, `None` would be used for that purpose.
- Counting loops are typically written using `for … in range(…)`.
- You can take advantage of the fact that negative list indices refer to positions relative to the end of the list.
- Write a docstring.  It's a good habit.

### Suggested solution

```
def linear_probe(x, lst):
    """
    Put integer x into a list at position x % len(lst), probing
    backwards until a free spot is found.  Raise IndexError if
    the list is full.
    """
    preferred_index = x % len(lst)
    for c in range(preferred_index, preferred_index - len(lst), -1):
        if lst[c] is None:
            lst[c] = x
            return
    raise IndexError('list is full')

def main():
    # Tests
    lst = [None] * 7
    linear_probe(1, lst)
    linear_probe(1, lst)
    linear_probe(1, lst)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```